# How can I see schedule of "pm2 cron "

Tags: linux, pm2

abstract) I want to see the schedule of pm2 cron job.

My predecessor left without documentation.

And I found some jobs running with "pm2 cron" on the server.

I found the command of job by "ctrl+r "

```
 pm2 start <command> --name '<job name>' --no-autorestart --cron-restart='00 1 * * *'
```

I couldn't find it because it was overwritten by another command.

```
pm2 restart <job name>
```

I tried to use history, but there isn't start command of the job

`history | grep <job name>`

So I can't know what tasks are performed and when.

How can I find out?